# Issue using maven which can't see default repositories

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository

My issue is that maven can't update my local repository since it can see I guess the default repositories.

Here is my settings.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>D:\work\settings\localRepoMaven</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
    <offline>false</offline>
    <pluginGroups/>
    <proxies/>
    <servers/>
    <mirrors/>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>maven-repository</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>

        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>base</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <tiles.version>3.0.1</tiles.version>
        <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
                <version>${tiles.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version }</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Please note that I don't have any proxy and tested without settings.xml (to force maven use default settings) but in vain.

I'm using Spring Tools Suite version 3.6.3.SR1

I can't see the issue. Please help !

Comment: Why are you using `dependencyManagement` inside your war Maven project ? Also, you don't need to declare `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` since Maven adds it by default.

Comment: And you are using `<activeProfile>base</activeProfile>` in your settings.xml but no profile `base` has been defined. By the way `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>` is not necessary since it is Maven default.